# InputListener doesn't work with OrthographicCamera and Actors

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a Stage with OrthographicCamera and also I have a Actor with InputListener setter by addListener (from actor class). The problem is that the actor doesn't proccess input, but if in my screen I delete OrthographicCamera the Actor proccess the input, so, with OrthographicCamera Actor doesn't proccess input but it works if I remove OrthographicCamera.

Any advice?

I have the following code

```
public class Test implements Screen {

    private Game game;
    private Stage stage;
    private MemoryActor actor;
    private AssetManager manager;
    private boolean loaded = false;
    float width, height;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    public Test(Game game){
        this.game = game;
        stage = new Stage();
        manager = new AssetManager();
        manager.load("img.png",Texture.class);
        manager.load("img1.png",Texture.class);
        InputMultiplexer im = new InputMultiplexer();
        im.addProcessor(stage);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(im);
        height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
        camera.position.set(((width / 2)), ((height / 2)), 0);
        camera.update();
        stage.setViewport(new ExtendViewport(300,300, camera));
    }

    public void createActor(){
        Texture back = manager.get("img.png", Texture.class);
        actor = new MemoryActor(manager.get("img1.png", Texture.class), back,0,0,50,50);
        actor.setInputListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                System.out.println("down");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                System.out.println("up");

            }
        });
        stage.addActor(actor);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        if (manager.update()){
            if (!loaded){
                createActor();
                loaded = true;
            }
        }
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

and MemoryActor:

```
public class MemoryActor extends Actor {

    ...

    public MemoryActor(){}

    public MemoryActor(Texture texture, Texture texBack, float x, float y, float width, float height){
        ...
    }


    public void setInputListener(InputListener il){
        addListener(il);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not update the Stage's Viewport in resize.

Comment: I have added: stage.getViewport().update(width,height); in resize method and it doesn't work

Comment: Use update(width, height, true)

Comment: And also do `stage.act()` in render().

Comment: Yes, it's works!. Thanks. If you post a answer I mark your answer for more clarity.

Comment: One question. Why in the creation of viewport the height and width (new ExtendViewport(width,height, camera)) should be a float and when I update the viewport in the resize method with stage.getViewport().update(width,height, true); the height and width should be an integer?

Comment: That's because the `ExtendViewport` gives you the possibility to work with a "virtual" resolution, which could also be just 1x1. A screen can only have whole pixels, but you are still able to move your sprites by just half a pixel for example. If this would not be possible, you would have quite a big problem, because your most slow speed of moving would be 60px/s at a 60Hz framerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just registering the stage as an `InputProcessor` isn't enough. You also need to trigger the event processing of `Stage` via `stage.act()` in every frame.

Furthermore you need to properly update the stage's `Viewport` when a resize event occurs. This can be done via `stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true)`. Otherwise the stage will process the events based on incorrect assumptions about the screen size and might also render your stage not the way you want it. The `true` is important because it will also center the camera on the new screen size, which is necessary in case of UIs.